# How to change Flutter_blue read and write button designs

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, frontend, signals

Frontend looks of read and write command.
I need to change the design of read and write command on the bluetooth devcie screen.
I used the code from pauldemarco git repository.
But the device screen frontend design does not suit good for my application.
Can anyone share how to change the design of upload and download signal button on the user interface?

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'widgets.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:dproject/qrcode.dart';
void main() {
  // RenderErrorBox.backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => Scaffold(body:Center(child: Text("Click the Refresh Button"),));
  runApp(FlutterBlueApp());
  // static ErrorWidgetBuilder builder = _defaultErrorWidgetBuilder;
  // RenderErrorBox.textStyle = ui.TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent);
}

class FlutterBlueApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.unknown,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
              return FindDevicesScreen();
            }
            return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
          }),
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothOffScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BluetoothOffScreen({Key? key, this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothState? state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.bluetooth_disabled,
              size: 200.0,
              color: Colors.white54,
            ),
            Text(
              'Bluetooth Adapter is ${state != null ? state.toString().substring(15) : 'not available'}.',
              // style: Theme.of(context)
              //     .primaryTextTheme
              //     .subhead
              //     ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FindDevicesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Find Devices'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () =>
            FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 8)),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothDevice>>(
                stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2))
                    .asyncMap((_) => FlutterBlue.instance.connectedDevices),
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data!
                      .map((d) => ListTile(
                            // title: Text(d.toString()),
                            // subtitle: Text(d.id.toString()),
                            trailing: StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
                              stream: d.state,
                              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected,
                              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.data ==
                                    BluetoothDeviceState.connected) {
                                  return ElevatedButton(
                                    child: Text('OPEN'),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                DeviceScreen(device: d))),
                                  );
                                }
                                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                              },
                            ),
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot){ 
                  List<ScanResult> data = [];
                  //  print("sh");
                  for(int i=0;i<snapshot.data!.length;i++)
                  { 
                    // print("sh");
                    // print(snapshot.data![i]);
                    if(snapshot.data![i].device.id.toString()=='FC:67:78:5D:96:EF'){
                      data.add(snapshot.data![i]);
                    }
                  }
                  // print(data);
                  return Column(
                  children: data
                      .map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                          result: r,
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            r.device.connect();
                            return                         DeviceScreen(device: r.device); //FlutterBlueApp();
                          })),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                );
                },
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: StreamBuilder<bool>(
        stream: FlutterBlue.instance.isScanning,
        initialData: false,
        builder: (c, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data!) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.stop),
              onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance.stopScan(),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            );
          } else {
            return FloatingActionButton(
                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () => FlutterBlue.instance
                    .startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 8)));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DeviceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DeviceScreen({Key? key, required this.device}) : super(key: key);
  final BluetoothDevice device;

  List<int> _getRandomBytes() {
    final math = Random();
    return [
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255),
      math.nextInt(255)
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> _buildServiceTiles(List<BluetoothService> services) {
    List<BluetoothService> data = [];
       print("sh%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%@@@@");
      for(int i=0;i<services.length;i++)
      {
        print("sh####################################");
        // print(services[i]);
        if(i==2){
          data.add(services[i]);
        }
      }
      // print(data);
    return data //services
        .map(
          (s) => ServiceTile(
            service: s,
            characteristicTiles: s.characteristics
                .map(
                  (c) => CharacteristicTile(
                    characteristic: c,
                    onReadPressed: () {
                      c.read();
                    },
                    onWritePressed: () async {
                      await c.write([1], withoutResponse: false);
                      await c.read();
                    // ElevatedButton(
                    //   // style: style,
                    //   onPressed: null,
                    //   child: const Text('Disabled'),
                    // );
                    },
                    onNotificationPressed: () async {
                      await c.setNotifyValue(!c.isNotifying);
                      await c.read();
                    },
                    descriptorTiles: c.descriptors
                        .map(
                          (d) => DescriptorTile(
                            descriptor: d,
                            onReadPressed: () => d.read(),
                            onWritePressed: () => d.write([1]),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
        //  print(c.read);
  }
  //  @override
  //   State<DeviceScreen> createState() => _DeviceScreenState();
  // }
  // class _DeviceScreenState extends State<DeviceScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("BITLOCK"),//device.name
        actions: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
            stream: device.state,
            initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
            builder: (c, snapshot) {
              VoidCallback? onPressed;
              String text;
              switch (snapshot.data) {
                case BluetoothDeviceState.connected:
                  onPressed = () => device.disconnect();
                  text = 'DISCONNECT';
                  break;
                case BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected:
                  onPressed = () => device.connect();
                  text = 'CONNECT';
                  break;
                default:
                  onPressed = null;
                  text = snapshot.data.toString().substring(21).toUpperCase();
                  break;
              }
              return TextButton(
                  onPressed: onPressed,
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .primaryTextTheme
                        .button
                        ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                  ));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
              stream: device.state,
              initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.connecting,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                leading: (snapshot.data == BluetoothDeviceState.connected)
                    ? Icon(Icons.bluetooth_connected)
                    : Icon(Icons.bluetooth_disabled),
                title: Text(((){
                    if(snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[1]=="connected"){
                      return 'Your Lock is ${snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[1]} to your device.';
                    }
                    return 'Your Lock is ${snapshot.data.toString().split('.')[1]} from your device.';
                    })()),
                // subtitle: Text('${device.id}'),
                trailing: StreamBuilder<bool>(
                  stream: device.isDiscoveringServices,
                  initialData: false,
                  builder: (c, snapshot) => IndexedStack(
                    index: snapshot.data! ? 1 : 0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                        onPressed: () => device.discoverServices(),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: SizedBox(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          width: 18.0,
                          height: 18.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: null,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: device.mtu,
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                // title: Text('MTU Size'),
                // subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data} bytes'),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
                  onPressed: () => device.requestMtu(223),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothService>>(
              stream: device.services,
              initialData: [],
              builder: (c, snapshot) {
                return Column(
                  children: _buildServiceTiles(snapshot.data!),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Post code, acess to to your code, etc. Not just a link with an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found.
You will find widgets.dart in the lib folder in which you are working with main.dart and other files.
You can edit this file according to required design.
In my case, I need to change Iconbutton icon in characteristics tile to change the design of read and write button.